# rails categories are not displaying in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

hi all im trying to make categories for each note that is created. Im displaying all the categories in the navbar but for some reason when i click on the categories it just displays all the posts instead of the posts in that category. can someone please help? thanks

notes_controller:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_note, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote,  :downvote]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :load_activities, only: [:index, :show, :new, :edit]

  def index
    if params[:category].blank?
      @notes = Note.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else 
      @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
      @notes=Note.where(category_id:@category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end

    if params[:search]
      @notes = Note.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @notes = Note.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  def show
    @comments = Comment.where(note_id: @note)
    @random_post = Note.where.not(id:@note).order("RANDOM()").first
  end

  def new
    @note = current_user.notes.build
  end

  def create
    @note = current_user.notes.build(note_params)
    if @note.save
      redirect_to @note
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @note.update(note_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Your message was successfully sent!"
      redirect_to @note
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @note.destroy
    redirect_to notes_path
  end

  def upvote
    @note.upvote_by current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js{ render 'upvote' }
    end
  end

  def downvote
    @note.downvote_from current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js{ render 'downvote' }
    end
  end

  private

  def find_note
    @note = Note.find(params[:id])
  end

  def note_params
    params.require(:note).permit(:title, :content, :category_id, :avatar)
  end

  def load_activities
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order('created_at DESC').limit(20)
  end
end
```

views/notes/index.html.erb:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <p id="intro">
    Hello
    <%= current_user.name %>
    <h1>  
      <%=@category_id%> 
    </h1>
    <br/>
    <span>
      Share your inspiratikkkon and see what's inspiring others.
    </span>
  </p>
<% else %>
  <p id="intro">
    What's your muse?
    <br/>
    <span>
      Share your inspiration and see what's inspiring others.
    </span>
  </p>
<% end %>

<div id="posts">
<% unless @notes.blank? %>
  <% @notes.each do |note| %>
    <div class="post">
      <div class="post_image">
        <%= image_tag note.avatar.url(:medium)%>
      </div>
      <div class="post_content">
        <div class="title">
          <h2>
            <%= link_to note.title, note %>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="data clearfix">
          <p class="username" style="font-size:20px;">
            <%= link_to note.user.name, note.user %>
            <span class="user-menu_profile-pic"><%= image_tag note.user.avatar.url(:thumb) %></span>
          </p>
          <p class="buttons">
            <span>
              <i class="fa fa-comments-o" style="font-size:30px;"></i>
            </span>
            <%= link_to like_note_path(note), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
              yeah your life sucks!
              <%= (note.get_upvotes.size)%>
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to dislike_note_path(note), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
              You deserve it!
              <%= (note.get_downvotes.size) %>
            <% end %>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% else %>
  <h2>Add a Note</h2>
  asdfasdfasdf
  ;ldldldldldl
  <p>
    It appears you haven't created any stories yet... 
    Lets fix that. Why don't you go ahead and create your story.
  </p>
  <button>
    <%= link_to "New Note", new_note_path %>
  </button>
<% end %>
```

layout.html.erb:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">it1d</a>
</li>
<
<% Category.all.each do |category| %>
  <li 'divider-vertical'>
    <%= link_to category.name, notes_path(category: category.name) %>
  </li>
<%end%>
```

routes.rb:

```
authenticated :user do
  root "notes#index", as: "authenticated_root"
end
resources :notes do
  member do
    put "like", to: "notes#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "notes#downvote"
  end
  resources :comments
end
```

Comment: `<li 'divider-vertical'>` is it `<li class="divider-vertical">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `index` action, you perform two `if` evaluations, one with `params[:category]` and other with `params[:search]` and both set `@notes`:

```
def index
  if params[:category].blank?
    @notes = Note.all.order("created_at DESC")
  else 
    @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
    @notes=Note.where(category_id:@category_id).order("created_at DESC")
  end

  if params[:search]
    @notes = Note.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @notes = Note.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

`@notes` will always be set to `@notes = Note.all.order("created_at DESC")` since the generated links do not provide a `search` parameter.

And even if a `search` parameter is provided, `@notes` will still be overriden by `@notes = Note.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")`.

So you need to change the logic in your controller, otherwise `@notes` will never set to `Note.where(category_id:@category_id).order("created_at DESC")`.

---

Not related to your problem, but worth mentioning:

You could change this line in *form.html.erb*:

```
<%= link_to category.name, notes_path(category: category.id) %>
```

And then, in your `index` action you will just do:

```
if params[:category].blank?
  @notes = Note.all.order("created_at DESC")
else 
  @notes=Note.where(category_id: params[:category]).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

And save yourself that extra query to the DB to set `@category_id`.

Comment: so do i put the search in to a different route?

Comment: Yes, would recommend a different route for your search.

Comment: @LeonBogod Check the updated answer, i also added a tip (not related to the problem) that could be useful.